# Why is my sidebar stuck in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css, responsive, sidebar

My sidebar seems to be stuck right beside my second article on the page and won't move up to float beside the main content. Could someone please take a look at the code and see if they can tell what the problem is? I have been trying to get it unstuck for hours. I truly have no idea why it will not sit next to the content. Here is an image where you can see the problem:

[image]

```css
body {
  background-image: url("billeder/bgorange.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  /* Base font size (14px)? 7%*/
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
}

.body {
  width: 95%;
}

.maincontent {
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}

.topcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: none;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
  padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%
}

.bottomcontent {
  background-color: white;
  float: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 2% 0 2% 0;
  padding: 1% 5% 3% 3%
}


/* SIDEBAR!***************************************************************/

.top-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.middle-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.bottom-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<header class="mainheader">

  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Forside</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<div id="banner"></div>
<div class="maincontent">


  <div class="content">
    <article class="topcontent">
      <header>
        <h2><a href="#" title="first post">Artikel</a></h2>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="post-info"> Info om denne boks</p>
      </footer>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod temporvoluptua. At vero eo </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <article class="bottomcontent">
      <header>
        <h2><a href="#" title="second post">Second post</a></h2>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="post-info"> Info </p>
      </footer>
      <p>takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>

<aside class="top-sidebar">
  <article>
    <h2>top sidebar</h2>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, com.</p>
  </article>
</aside>

<aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article>
    <h2>Middle sidebar</h2>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, conserebum.</p>
  </article>
</aside>

<aside class="bottom-sidebar">
  <article>
    <h2>Bottom sidebar</h2>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, conrebum.</p>
  </article>
</aside>

<footer class="mainfooter"></footer>
```

Comment: Maybe you should add box-sizing: border-box for elements on this site

Comment: @Ginger You could also have solved this by using inline-block positioning on your aside and relative positioning instead of float:left; on your sidebar https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/emsLf1oL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is the order of your floats. The order goes:

1. `.content`
2. `.content`
3. `.top-sidebar`

When you float elements, if the next element in line won't fit in the space provided, it reflows to the next line (below the previous element).

This is what's happening:

`.content` is 75% of browser width. Since it's floated the next element will attempt to butt up next to it if there's enough room. The remaining room is 25% of browser width. The second `.content` is 75% of browser width and cannot fit, so it reflows. The next element is `.top-sidebar` which is 24% of browser width (after adding up margin and padding percentages) and will fit in the remaining 25%, so the sidebar starts there.

How do we fix it?

Move your properties from `.content` to `.maincontent`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("billeder/bgorange.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  /* Base font size (14px)? 7%*/
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
}

.body {
  width: 95%;
}

.maincontent {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.content {
}

.topcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: none;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
  padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%
}

.bottomcontent {
  background-color: white;
  float: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 2% 0 2% 0;
  padding: 1% 5% 3% 3%
}


/* SIDEBAR!***************************************************************/

.top-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.middle-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.bottom-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<header class="mainheader">

  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Forside</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<div id="banner"></div>
<div class="maincontent">


  <div class="content">
    <article class="topcontent">
      <header>
        <h2><a href="#" title="first post">Artikel</a></h2>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="post-info"> Info om denne boks</p>
      </footer>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod temporvoluptua. At vero eo </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <article class="bottomcontent">
      <header>
        <h2><a href="#" title="second post">Second post</a></h2>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="post-info"> Info </p>
      </footer>
      <p>takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>

<aside class="top-sidebar">
  <article>
    <h2>top sidebar</h2>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, com.</p>
  </article>
</aside>

<aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article>
    <h2>Middle sidebar</h2>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, conserebum.</p>
  </article>
</aside>

<aside class="bottom-sidebar">
  <article>
    <h2>Bottom sidebar</h2>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, conrebum.</p>
  </article>
</aside>

<footer class="mainfooter"></footer>
```

Now the order is:

1. `.maincontent`
2. `.top-sidebar`

This is what you want with your floats, have two high-level containers that you place the real content in and mimimze the floats.

Ultimately I would use flexbox if you're beginning to build a site today.

Basic example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}
.content section {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: gold;
}

sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <main>
    <section>
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  
  <sidebar>
    <section>
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </p>
    </section>
  </sidebar>
  
</div>

<footer>Site footer</footer>
```

Comment: THAT WAS IT! Thank you so much!! You are a truly wonderful person!